# Printf before system boot

Tags: printf, boot, bios, vga

I am using Openbsd, when the kernel has not yet loaded, and you are in the boot console, the printf function writes directly to the VGA memory 0xb8000.

Using the i / o ports maybe?

[boot code](https://github.com/openbsd/src/blob/master/sys/stand/boot/boot.c)

[prinf code](https://github.com/openbsd/src/blob/master/sys/kern/subr_prf.c)

The printf code, according to manual.

That is my question, it is supposed to write in memory directly, since the kernel has not been loaded, or anything like that, someone can guide me.

Thanks.

Comment: You can read/write directly to video memory without any special processing. The video is memory mapped so you can write and read to it like any other memory (video memory is slower though)

Comment: But, in this case the boot code calls printf, how does it print the characters on the screen?

the kernel is not loaded. I suppose you will have to use some similar method? Thanks Michael.

Comment: Without a kernel loaded, directly in a bootloader you can write data directly to the memory  with no OS. _C_ allows you to write directly to the text memory address (0xb8000) or the graphical memory address if not in text mode like any other memory in _C_. If your computer has text video mode then _C_ code like this would write `Hello` to the video display with no OS present https://pastebin.com/MHQpiHAp

Comment: Thanks for the example, if I am reading the information that is in osdev, it is as you describe it in your code.

But my interest in if it is not that printf, if not the BIOS. But it would be out of the question that I have asked, I will make a new one, with what I already know, thanks to you, or if you allow me to write to you personally, so that you can help me. Thanks.